# How can i configure my mail server in open atrium?

Tags: php, email, drupal, open-atrium

i have just succesfully installed open atrium, but i can't find the configuration of the mailserver... i currently cant send any mails because there is no SMTP Server defined, an without mails being send, no new users can be registered, because they recieve their pasword via mail...

i hope that somebody can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Open Atrum works the same way as drupal [this](http://drupal.org/node/92579) should help in short:

1. Set up a mail server locally
2. change your php.ini settings to point to a mail server

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using the [SMTP module](http://drupal.org/project/smtp).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [OpenAtrium Installation docs](https://community.openatrium.com/documentation-en/node/30), all you need to do is enable the [standard Drupal cron job]. That worked for me in my OpenAtrium installation. Just to be clear, I did not have to alter php.ini or install the Drupal SMTP module.